# How to count number of emails and average of emails sent by hour?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi

I'm working on reports with Power BI. I want to get for each hour the number of emails sent. I did the query in SQL Server but I'm having a difficulty translating it to DAX to create a measure.Also I want to get the average number of emails sent by hour.

My query is like below  :

```
 select datepart(hour,CreatedDate), count(MailId) from [DW PI].[dbo].[Email Fact] 
      group by datepart(hour,CreatedDate)
      order by count(MailId) desc
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an extra column on your table:

```
Hour = HOUR(Email Fact[CreatedDate])
```

Now you add this column to your table visual together with the MailId.

Last point: you want a count of the MailId, not the Sum.
For you that is the count of MailId
[image]